# How to update image's upvotes and downvotes based on the records in my votes table?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I've created upvote/downvote functionality which uses a table called voted. Each record in that table contains an id, user_id, image_id and vote which is integer ( 1 for upvote, 0 for downvote ). My images table contains 2 columns, one for amount of upvotes and 1 for amount of downvotes.

Now the problem is that I'm not sure how exactly to do the update of the upvotes/downvotes columns in my image table and when exactly to update them. I assume I should do that right after voting but I'm not completely sure.

Vote model:

```
class Vote extends Model
{
    public function images(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Images');
    }
}
```

Image model:

```
class Image extends Model
{
    public function votes(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Vote');
    }
}
```

Images table:

```
Schema::create('images', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id')->unsigned();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('description')->nullable()->default(null);
            $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
            $table->string('file_name');
            $table->string('upvotes')->default(0);
            $table->string('downvotes')->default(0);
            $table->string('views')->default(0);
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
        });
```

Votes table:

```
Schema::create('votes', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id')->unsigned();
            $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
            $table->integer('image_id')->unsigned();
            $table->boolean('vote');
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
        });
```

VotesController

```
class VotesController extends Controller
{
    public function voteImage(Request $request){
        $image_id = $request['imageId'];
        $isLike = $request['isLike'] === 'true';
        $update = false;
        $image = Image::find($image_id);
        if (!$image){
            return null;
        }
        $user = Auth::user();
        $vote = $user->votes()->where('image_id', $image_id)->first();
        if ($vote) {
            $already_vote = $vote->vote;
            $update = true;
            if ($already_vote == $isLike){
                $vote->delete();
                return null;
            }
        } else {
            $vote = new Vote();
        }
        $vote->vote = $isLike;
        $vote->user_id = $user->id;
        $vote->image_id = $image->id;
        if ($update) {
            $vote->update();
        } else {
            $vote->save();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: You are for a solution or a code review?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to do this after any change in the votes.
add method to Image model

```
class Image extends Model
{
    public function votes(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Vote');
    }

    public function updateVotes()
    {
        $this->upvotes = Vote::where('image_id', $this->id)->where('vote', true)->count();
        $this->downvotes = Vote::where('image_id', $this->id)->where('vote', false)->count();
        $this->save();
    }
}
```

and user it in controller

```
class VotesController extends Controller
{
    public function voteImage(Request $request){
        $image_id = $request['imageId'];
        $isLike = $request['isLike'] === 'true';
        $update = false;
        $image = Image::find($image_id);
        if (!$image){
            return null;
        }
        $user = Auth::user();
        $vote = $user->votes()->where('image_id', $image_id)->first();
        if ($vote) {
            $already_vote = $vote->vote;
            $update = true;
            if ($already_vote == $isLike){
                $vote->delete();
                $image->updateVotes();
                return null;
            }
        } else {
            $vote = new Vote();
        }
        $vote->vote = $isLike;
        $vote->user_id = $user->id;
        $vote->image_id = $image->id;
        if ($update) {
            $vote->update();
        } else {
            $vote->save();
        }
        $image->updateVotes();
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Works perfectly and it's only a couple lines of code. My way I devised required quite a lot of repetitive code.